# Receiving error java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, odoo, onclicklistener

I have catch this error "Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread Make sure your adapter calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` when its content changes." sometimes when click on listview `onClickListener`.

I dont get this everytime. I get this error at random sometime. But i dont understand from where this error is coming. I am using Asynctask.

Here is my Asynctask code,

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>() {
    boolean error_server;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(ReportingList.this);
        Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        Asycdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        Asycdialog.show();
    };

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            arraylist_product_category.clear();
            JSONArray jArray_cate = new JSONArray();
            jArray_cate.put("id");
            jArray_cate.put("name");

            JSONObject fieldsAccumulates_cate = new JSONObject();
            fieldsAccumulates_cate.put("fields", jArray_cate);
            JSONObject jo_cate = odoo.search_read("product.category", fieldsAccumulates_cate);

            JSONArray result_cate = jo_cate.getJSONArray("records");
            if (result_cate.length() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < result_cate.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo1 = result_cate.getJSONObject(i);
                    WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(jo1.getString("id"), jo1.getString("name"));
                    arraylist_product_category.add(wp);
                }
            } else {
                publishProgress(1);
            }

            //adapter_product_category = new ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);
            //adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged();
            is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error_server = true;
        }
        return null;
    };

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        if (values[0] == 1)
            et_product_category.setText("");
    };

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        adapter_product_category = new ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);
        //is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
        if(Asycdialog.isShowing())
            Asycdialog.dismiss();
        if (error_server)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    };
}.execute(null, null, null);
```

Please help me with this error. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my print stack trace,

```
02-19 19:03:53.299 184-1088/? E/IMGSRV: :0: PVRDRMOpen: TP3, ret = 40
02-19 19:03:53.409 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
02-19 19:03:53.409 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
02-19 19:03:53.419 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131493109, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.serpentcs.primemedical.adapter.ListViewAdapter)]
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3687)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3485)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7758)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2224)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2071)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1518)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:746)
    at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2019)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7995)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4046)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3469)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3438)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3545)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3446)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3469)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3438)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3446)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5694)
        at android.view.ViewRootIm
02-19 19:03:53.419 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-19 19:03:53.419 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430f3140)
02-19 19:03:53.419 1175-1175/com.serpentcs.primemedical E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.serpentcs.primemedical, PID: 1175
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131493109, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.serpentcs.primemedical.adapter.ListViewAdapter)]
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1555)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3687)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3485)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7758)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2224)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1959)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2230)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1973)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2071)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1518)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:746)
at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2019)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7995)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4046)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3469)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3438)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3545)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3446)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3602)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3469)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3438)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3446)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3419)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.de
02-19 19:03:53.429 534-954/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.serpentcs.primemedical/.ReportingList
```

Here is my updated code after adding adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged();,

```
new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>() {
                    boolean error_server;

                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(ReportingList.this);
                        Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                        Asycdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                        Asycdialog.show();
                    };

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                        try {
                            arraylist_product_category.clear();
                            JSONArray jArray_cate = new JSONArray();
                            jArray_cate.put("id");
                            jArray_cate.put("name");

                            JSONObject fieldsAccumulates_cate = new JSONObject();
                            fieldsAccumulates_cate.put("fields", jArray_cate);
                            JSONObject jo_cate = odoo.search_read("product.category", fieldsAccumulates_cate);

                            JSONArray result_cate = jo_cate.getJSONArray("records");
                            if (result_cate.length() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < result_cate.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject jo1 = result_cate.getJSONObject(i);
                                    WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(jo1.getString("id"), jo1.getString("name"));
                                    arraylist_product_category.add(wp);
                                }
                            } else {
                                publishProgress(1);
                            }

                            adapter_product_category = new ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);
                            adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            error_server = true;
                        }
                        return null;
                    };

                    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                        if (values[0] == 1)
                            et_product_category.setText("");
                    };

                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                        //adapter_product_category = new ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);
                        adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
                        if(Asycdialog.isShowing())
                            Asycdialog.dismiss();
                        if (error_server)
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    ;
                }.execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: when ever you change data of listview always call notifyDataSetChanged() on listview

Comment: Can you provide  Printstackstrace?

Comment: You are missing `adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged()`. In both `doInBackground()` and `onPostExecute()` places.

Comment: I inserted adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged() inboth the methods, still I am getting the same error randomly. I am inserting my print stack trace in the question.

Comment: Update the question with your updated code, so that we remain in-sync please.

Answer (score 1):

Declare adapter globally in class -

```
ListViewAdapter adapter_product_category = new    ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);


new AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>() {
                boolean error_server;

                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    Asycdialog = new ProgressDialog(ReportingList.this);
                    Asycdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    Asycdialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    Asycdialog.show();
                };

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                    try {
                        arraylist_product_category.clear();
                        JSONArray jArray_cate = new JSONArray();
                        jArray_cate.put("id");
                        jArray_cate.put("name");

                        JSONObject fieldsAccumulates_cate = new JSONObject();
                        fieldsAccumulates_cate.put("fields", jArray_cate);
                        JSONObject jo_cate = odoo.search_read("product.category", fieldsAccumulates_cate);

                        JSONArray result_cate = jo_cate.getJSONArray("records");
                        if (result_cate.length() > 0) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < result_cate.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jo1 = result_cate.getJSONObject(i);
                                WorldPopulation wp = new WorldPopulation(jo1.getString("id"), jo1.getString("name"));
                                arraylist_product_category.add(wp);
                            }
                        } else {
                            publishProgress(1);
                        }

                        //adapter_product_category = new ListViewAdapter(ReportingList.this, arraylist_product_category);
                        //adapter_product_category.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        error_server = true;
                    }
                    return null;
                };

                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                    if (values[0] == 1)
                        et_product_category.setText("");
                };

                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    // Set notifyDataSetChanged for updates
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    //is_adapter_product_category_filled = true;
                    if(Asycdialog.isShowing())
                        Asycdialog.dismiss();
                    if (error_server)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server not reachable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                ;
            }.execute(null, null, null);
```